# How to create an Android App form and save data to a data base on a server?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, forms

I am looking for some tutorials and guidelines on how to save information entered into a form containing text fields to a data base on the server.

On a second level, I would like to be able to send notifications to the application on the phone based on information stored in the data base.

Thanks...

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html look for the one

Comment: i think google will give you more options....

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to store data locally in sqlite in the device and send it to the server probably through a webservice, or directly connect to SQL Server using asynctask. Google more about these.

Notifications, again webservices or c2dm will help